# How to take the two table values and make in json response

Tags: php, php-5.6

Here I want to take the count from MySQL, I am two table based on trip id I want to take the count, how can do this?.

Here, trip is common for both table and trip id 1 having three counts and trip id 2 having two counts.

> trip_details (Table Name)

```
 tripId        cabNo 

  1          BMW4455

  2          Audi005
```

> trip_member (Table Name)

```
id    tripId    empId

1     1       100
2     1       101
3     1       102
4     2       105
5     2       106
```

> Expected results

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": [
    {
        "tripId": "1",
        "cabNo": "BMW4455",
        "empcount": "3"
        "employees": [
            {
                "empId": "100",
            },
            {
                "empId": "101",
            },
            {
                "empId": "102",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "tripId": "2",
        "cabNo": "Ad2K2001",
        "count": "2"
        "employees": [
            {
                "empId": "100",
            },
            {
                "empId": "101",
            },
            {
                "empId": "102",
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

> I tried but i am not getting my exact answer  **My Code here**

```
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM trip_details a INNER JOIN trip_member b ON a.tripId=b.tripId GROUP BY a.tripId";
  $mysql = mysql_query($sql);
  $count =mysql_num_rows($mysql);
  if($count > 0){
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql)) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
  $arrayName = array('status' => 'success', 'count' => $count, 'data' =>$data );
  echo json_encode($arrayName);
 }else{
$arrayName = array('status' => 'error', 'data' =>'Data not found' );
  echo json_encode($arrayName);
 }
```

> i am getting output

```
{
"status": "success",
"count": 2,
"data": [
    {
        "tripId": "1",
        "cabNo": "BMW4455",
        "driverId": "DRE001",
        "routeId": "1",
        "tripDate": "",
        "startTime": "",
        "endTime": "",
        "shiftId": "1",
        "tripStatus": "0",
        "id": "1",
        "empId": "100",
        "callStartTime": "",
        "callEndTime": "",
        "cabReachingTime": "",
        "pickupTime": "",
        "dropTime": "",
        "dropStatus": "",
        "otp": "",
        "pickupotpStatus": "",
        "empPresentStatus": ""
    },
    {
        "tripId": "2",
        "cabNo": "Audi005",
        "driverId": "DRV101",
        "routeId": "2",
        "tripDate": "",
        "startTime": "",
        "endTime": "",
        "shiftId": "1",
        "tripStatus": "0",
        "id": "4",
        "empId": "105",
        "callStartTime": "",
        "callEndTime": "",
        "cabReachingTime": "",
        "pickupTime": "",
        "dropTime": "",
        "dropStatus": "",
        "otp": "",
        "pickupotpStatus": "",
        "empPresentStatus": ""
    }
]
}
```

Comment: what your getting now ?

Comment: First of all the `mysql` extension has been deprecated please use `mysqli` instead. Please also show the output you get.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need counts, you should change your query to:

```
SELECT count(*) as count, tm.tripId from trip_details td
JOIN trip_member tm on tm. tripId = td.tripId
GROUP by tm.tripId
```

Comment: Mr@Milan Chheda, how to make json like my expected  results